# Extract key based on specifc value from json stored as longtext

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column that stores value for user attribute. Te column type is longtext.

For example,

```
{"1":1,"15607":1,"1345":2}
```

I want to extract only the keys which have value as 1, which means i should get 1 and 15607.

I tried using json_search

```
json_search(cast(attribute_value AS JSON as json), 'all', 1)
```

But this returns no data.

Is it doable using json_search or even without using json and just sql?

Comment: *I want to extract only the keys which have value as 1* Gather all keys with JSON_KEYS(). Parse the output on separate keys. Investigate each separate key value. Return only matched keys.

Comment: *I tried using json_search* [JSON_SEARCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) returns the path to the given **string** within a JSON document. So you cannot search numeric or special (true/false/null) values using this funciton.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo showing steps to get to what you want:

```
mysql> set @att = '{"1":1,"15607":1,"1345":2}';

mysql> select json_keys(@att);
+------------------------+
| json_keys(@att)        |
+------------------------+
| ["1", "1345", "15607"] |
+------------------------+

mysql> select j.* from json_table(json_keys(@att), '$[*]' columns (k int path '$')) as j;
+-------+
| k     |
+-------+
|     1 |
|  1345 |
| 15607 |
+-------+

mysql> select j.k, att.v 
  from json_table(json_keys(@att), '$[*]' columns (k int path '$')) as j 
  cross join (select cast(@att as json) as v) as att;
+-------+---------------------------------+
| k     | v                               |
+-------+---------------------------------+
|     1 | {"1": 1, "1345": 2, "15607": 1} |
|  1345 | {"1": 1, "1345": 2, "15607": 1} |
| 15607 | {"1": 1, "1345": 2, "15607": 1} |
+-------+---------------------------------+

mysql> select j.k, json_extract(att.v, concat('$."',j.k,'"')) as v 
  from json_table(json_keys(@att), '$[*]' columns (k int path '$')) as j 
  cross join (select cast(@att as json) as v) as att;
+-------+------+
| k     | v    |
+-------+------+
|     1 | 1    |
|  1345 | 2    |
| 15607 | 1    |
+-------+------+

mysql> select k, v from (
  select j.k, json_extract(att.v, concat('$."',j.k,'"')) as v 
    from json_table(json_keys(@att), '$[*]' columns (k int path '$')) as j 
    cross join (select cast(@att as json) as v) as att) as t 
where v = 1;
+-------+------+
| k     | v    |
+-------+------+
|     1 | 1    |
| 15607 | 1    |
+-------+------+
```

If this seems like a lot of work, it is. Using JSON in MySQL is seldom a good idea. It makes queries much more complex, harder to write, and harder to optimize.

I recommend avoiding using JSON in MySQL if possible. Use normal rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have to use this as a single query as part of a workflow and can't be split. Is there way to achieve this using other sql functions(non-json)?

Comment: You can do it in one query — the last query I showed. I only broke it up to show the logic, because most people say they don't understand it if I show only the last step.

Comment: I tried the query after adding my details( raa is table name and attribute_value is the column name). But once i run the query it keeps loading/processing forever..

select k, v from (
  select j.k, json_extract(att.v, concat('$."',j.k,'"')) as v 
    from json_table((select json_keys( cast(attribute_value as json)) from raa where ATTRIBUTE_NAME='USERRANKJSON'), '$[*]' columns (k int path '$')) as j 
    cross join (select cast(attribute_value as json) from raa where ATTRIBUTE_NAME='USERRANKJSON') as v) as att) as t 
where v = 1;

Comment: That sounds inconvenient. Maybe you shouldn't use JSON, and instead use normal rows and columns, with indexes to optimize access.